# Typescript: how to call json() method on result of promise when result could be of type Response or void?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, try-catch, asynchronous-javascript

In my React Native app I make an API call and then try to apply the `json()` method to the result, like this:

```
await fetch(...)
  .catch(e => {...})
  .then(res => res.json().then(...)
```

Typescript throws a warning on `json()` saying `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'void | Response'`.

**What I Want To Know:**

1. Is there a way to prevent this warning?
2. If I swap the order of `catch` and `then`, the error goes away. But I want `catch` to catch only errors from `fetch()`, not from the code in the `then` block. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you actually *handling* the error in that `catch` block? It might make sense to just re-throw a different error with a better error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
await fetch(...)
  .catch(e => {...})
  .then(res => res?.json?.().then(...)
```

> The **optional chaining** operator (**`?.`**) enables you to read the value of a
> property located deep within a chain of connected objects without
> having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Comment: Can you explain what happens in this code?

Comment: @gkeenley I added a description of the operator.

Comment: So does `res?.json()` call the `json` method only if `res` is valid, and `res?.json?.().then(...)` call `then(...)` only if the output of `json()` is valid?

Comment: @gkeenley `res?.json` reads `json` only if `res` isn't nullish and `res?.json?.()` calls `json` only if `res?.json` isn't nullish. It doesn't check the returned value of `json`.

Answer (score 0):

> If I swap the order of `catch` and `then`, the error goes away. But I want `catch` to catch only errors from `fetch()`, not from the code in the `then` block. Is there a way to achieve this?

Yes, use [`.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572):

```
await fetch(...).then(res =>
  res.json().then(…)
, e => {
  …
});
```